# Connecting multiple phone calls via VOIP using C#

Tags: c#, voip

I am trying to achieve below

Me (customer) press a button to speak to agent (from mobile app - Xamarin)

```
Then login tries to connect to (gets top 5 agents list from database / JSON  - top 5 agents will vary every time based on time)

Agent 1 - rings agent 1 mobile phone as normal call, if No answer after 25 seconds  
Agent 2 - ring for 25 secs 
Agent 3 - ring, connected
```

Once call finished log date time of call

I am happy to use any VOIP provider or any other solutions.

Edit

> Sorry.. I am looking at ways to do this, contacted RingCentral and
>   Vonage, they don't have any API, so not sure where or how can I
>   achieve, any suggestions please.

Comment: Have you tried something? Or you do expect us to do your homework?

Comment: Sorry.. i am looking at ways to do this, contacted RingCentral and Vonage, they dont have any API, so not sure where or how can i achieve, any suggestions please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why i did not come across `Twilio`.

Twilio offers best solutions for above, they have API that's suitable for above scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can start trying some of these:

- http://www.pjsip.org/
- http://naudio.codeplex.com/
- http://www.abtosoftware.com/products/voip-sip-sdk
- http://www.independentsoft.com/sip/index.html
- https://github.com/sipsorcery/sipsorcery

Or ask here:

http://www.sipforum.org/